# WordPress Posts count is wrong

Tags: wordpress

I recently deleted all of my posts. Now when I'm on the Admin Posts page, I have a count of All(87) but No posts found.

[image: All Posts]

I've installed and ran WP-Optimize but the number 87 still appears with No posts found.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to look what's in the trash (and permanently delete that if you are sure about it)

Comment: There's no trash, just what you see in the image above.

Comment: There *IS*  a trash for posts (and pages) in Wordpress

Comment: I understand normally there's a trash for deleted posts but for some reason the link to the trash is not showing on the Posts page, as you can see from the image I posted. I don't know where that number 87 is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

I restored a backup and used the plugin Bulk Delete to delete all posts. Problem solved.